# For a continuous random variable, why does $P(a < Z < b) = P(a \leq Z < b) = P(a < Z \leq b) = P(a \leq Z \leq b)$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, continuous-data

My textbook puts this in a sidebox with the heading "Note" and doesn't explain why. Could you tell me why this statement holds?

$P(a < Z < b) = P(a \leq Z < b) = P(a < Z \leq b) = P(a \leq Z \leq b)$

Comment: One could almost take these assertions as *definitions* of "continuous." What, then, is *your* definition of a continuous random variable?

Comment: For a continuous random variable, what is $P(Z=a)$ and $P(Z=b)$?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on probability distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_probability_distribution#Discrete_probability_distribution) does a pretty good job of explaining this.  [Ultimately](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_probability_distribution#Continuous_probability_distribution) it invokes the fact that the CDF is continuous, whence the probability of any single point must be zero.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing formal to add to this, but an analogy that really helped me to understand this came from a calculus text. Imagine you have an iron pipe of a certain length and weight. And you wish to cut it into two pieces. If the pipe is say 1 m long you might want to cut it in half at the 0.5 mark. Now think of the pipe's weight as some constant times the length of the pipe, (we assume that all cross-sections of equal length has the same weight).

Cutting the pipe in half at the 0.5 m mark - how much weight do you lose? Remember that the only cross-section you are removing is the 0.5 m mark itself. So what is the length of this cross-section? Consider that 0.49999999... is not apart of it, and neither is 0.5000000000...1, or any other point that is close to, but not equal to 0.5 - so the length of this cross-section is technically zero. Which means you're not really removing any weight at all.

This would explain why $\leq$ and $<$ are basically the same for continuous variables - including or excluding the endpoint really doesn't change anything - for any point you pick close to the endpoint, there is still an infinite amount of points between them.

Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 2):

First I will give the definition of an (absolutely) continuous random variable $Z$.

(Advanced probability is needed, you many skip it!)

Let $(\Omega,F, P)$ be a [probability space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) and let $Z:\Omega\rightarrow R^n$ be a random vector. The probability $P_X$ on $B(R^n)$ defined by $P_Z(A)=P\{Z\in A\}$, $A \in B(R^n)$ is called the distribution of $Z$. Now if $P_Z\ll \mu,$ where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $R^n$, (i.e. $P$ is [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) with respect to $\mu$) then we say that $Z$ is an (absolutely) continuous random vector. Now by using [Radon–Nikodym theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem), there exists a function $f: R^n\to[0,+\infty]$ such that $P_Z(A)=\int_{A}fd_{\mu}$ for all $A \in B(R^n)$. We call $f$ the density function of $Z$.

Now define the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of an absolutely continuous random variable $Z$ as: $$F_Z(z)=P(Z\leq z).$$

Before I give a formal proof, let's have an example of a continuous random varible that is uniformly distributed i.e. with a probability density function of $f(z)=1$  for $0\leq z \leq 1$ and 0 otherwise. Now let's try to find $P(z=0.5)$. We have $$P(z=0.5)\sim P(0.4< z\leq 0.6)=\int_{0.4}^{0.6}f(z)d_z=0.2.$$ We can shrink that interval to get a better approximation as follows: $$P(z=0.5)\sim P(0.49< z\leq 0.51)=\int_{0.49}^{0.51}f(z)d_z=0.02,$$ $$P(z=0.5)\sim P(0.499< z\leq 0.501)=\int_{0.499}^{0.501}f(z)d_z=0.002.$$ As you can see, these probabilities are converging to zero as we shrink the length of the interval. Now let's prove it formally. I am goig to show that for any continuous random variable $Z$, we have: $$P(Z=a)=0,$$ by using the CDF. $$P(Z=a)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}P(a-\epsilon< Z\leq a+\epsilon)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}F_Z(a+\epsilon)-\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}F_Z(a-\epsilon)\\=F_Z(a)-F_Z(a)=0,$$ since the CDF function, $F$, is a "continuous" function for the continuous random variable $Z$. Similarly $P(Z=b)=0$.
Finally note that $$P(A\bigcup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\bigcap B).$$ So $$P(a\leq Z<b)=P\Big(\{Z=a\}\bigcap \{a<Z<b\}\Big)=P(Z=a)+P(a<Z<b)\\=0+P(a<Z<b)=P(a<Z<b).$$ You can use the same argument for other equalities.

Comment: It appears this argument would apply equally well to any discrete distribution with a countably infinite set of possible values, but then the conclusions are obviously wrong, so something is the matter.

Comment: It would be great if you can show us how "the conclusions are obviously wrong" ...

Comment: In a discrete distribution--even one (like a Poisson or Negative Binomial) with countably infinite support--*every* value has nonzero probability, whereas your argument implies they all have zero probability.

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that $F_Z(z)$ being a _right-continuous_ function gives us that $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} F_Z(a-\epsilon) = F_Z(a).$$ The desired result requires _left-continuity_ of $F_Z(z)$, which of course holds since $F_Z(z)$ is both right-continuous and left-continuous for continuous random variables $Z$. Also, you _are_ using the fact that probability is a set-continuous function when you compute $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}P(a-\epsilon < Z \leq a+\epsilon)$ and assert that it is the same as $P\{\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} (a-\epsilon<Z<a+\epsilon)\}$.

Comment: .... and your latest revision re-inserts the mistaken attribution to right-continuity.

Comment: Thanks Dilip, I removed the term right :) As for your 2nd comments, I didn't change the order of probability and limit. It is asserting that those probabilities are converging to $P(Z=a)$, which can be seen from the given example and it is indeed true for any "continuous" random variable.

Comment: Your conclusion is *not* true for the definition of "continuous" you have provided. If you were to add some stronger conditions on $f$, such that $f$ be a continuous function except possibly at a discrete set of points, then your argument would work.  See [Wikipedia on "continuous probability distribution"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Continuous_probability_distribution) and also consult its link to [absolute continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_functions), where a counterexample [a Cantor function] is mentioned.

Comment: "I didn't change the order of probability and limit". Let's try a nonprobabilistic case. Let $g(x)$ denote a real function of a real variable $x$. Now suppose that there is _some_ sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ that _converges_ to $a$ and $g(x)$ has the property the sequence $g(x_1), g(x_2), \ldots$ _converges_ to $b$.  Does it necessarily follow that $g(a) = b$? Or do we need to assume something about $g(x)$, e.g. $g(x)$ is _continuous_ at $a$? Does the following _always_ hold? $$g\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n\right) = \lim_{n\to \infty} g(x_n)$$

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a more intuitive explanation is that for a continuous variable the contribution of the edges (e.g., $a$ or $b$) to the cumulative probability in the surrounding intervals (or semi-intervals) is negligibly small.